# How to create a target, add resources to that target and build the target using xcode command line tools?

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, documentation, xcode5

I am trying to use command line tools to create, add resources, build, archive and export to ipa in xcode. I could do the Build, Archive and Exporting to IPA through the command line tools(xcodebuild). But I also wanted to duplicate the target in the same project,add a new Info.plist to the duplicated target resource through command line itself. How to do it? I could not find any valuable answers by Googling.

Is there any other tools that can be used to perform these? I don't want to use the UI. Please, help me out.

Comment: Have you solved this , Is it possible to create target from command line

Comment: I would like to know more about this too. Did yo ever manage it?

Answer (score 1):

This should help you for create a target : https://deallocatedobjects.com/posts/building-xcode-projects-from-the-command-line

For add ressources it seems more complicated, but check this might help you : [Command line tool to add resources to an Xcode project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107170/command-line-tool-to-add-resources-to-an-xcode-project)

For build the target : https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/cpp-mac/GUID-05ED92FF-AEDC-4E9A-B640-CA3A681D9824.htm

Comment: Well, the link for copy resources mentions how to do using UI. doing though command line is the challenge. This will work if you do through UI. The link for creating target has not mentioned about creating or duplicating. It requires the target to be available in the xcode before we give this command. :(

Comment: Not sure everything is available in line tool, i'll try to do research. Why do you need to do this in line tools ?

Comment: I am trying to automate my release process using hudson as CI. It will use shell scripts running in the back-end. Basically, I am trying to create "Anyone can deploy" machine in our office :)

Comment: It seems a good idea, but very hard to do, try to contact the support of XCode, I think they will help you faster than here.

Comment: @Spidey did u find any solution my requirement also same